# Java not printing default unitialized value

Tags: java

I understand that Java objects that are only declared but not initialized are defaulted to the `null` value, but then why doesn't the following compile and print out null?

```
String a;
System.out.println(a);
```

Comment: Terminology note: you don't declare an *object* - you declare a *variable*. It's important to keep those two concepts separate in your mind.

Comment: @JonSkeet Ah, absolutely, thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [section 16 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-16.html):

> Each local variable (§14.4) and every blank final field (§4.12.4, §8.3.1.2) must have a definitely assigned value when any access of its value occurs.

Your code *will* work for non-final fields (instance or static variables) as they are initialized as per [section 4.12.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5)) but will cause a compile-time error for local variables due to this.

The same would be true if `a` were a primitive variable. Here's a short but complete program showing all of this:

```
class Test {

    static int x;
    static String y;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println(y);

        int lx;
        String ly;
        System.out.println(lx); // Compile-time error
        System.out.println(ly); // Compile-time error
    }
}
```

Output of the first two lines once the non-compiling lines have been removed:

```
0
null
```

Answer (score 4):

Fields of a class are initialized by default.

Like

```
class A {
  String a;

  public void doSomething() {
     System.out.println(a); //prints null
  }
}
```

But local variables must be explicitly initialized. So your code above won't work because `a` must be explicitly initialized.

You may want to read the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/), section [4.12.5. Initial Values of Variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5), where this behavior is explained in full detail.

Answer (score 2):

The instance variables which are object references are always initialized to null. But the same is not the case with local variables.

You need to explicitly initialize the local variables.

e.g.

```
String a = null;
System.out.println(a);
```

Comment: doh! I was doing it all in the main function.

Answer (score 0):

Fields in java must be initialized before you access them.
The class properties(fields) of reference type (for example) can be not initialized explicitly because they are guaranteed to be null-initialized before object construction (i mean the constructor code execution). This is the guarantee that you wont access the uninitialized field. 
There is no such logic about the local method fields so you must do it explicitly.